# WildFly web service configuration wsdl-port not working

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-8

The "modify wsdl address" feature described under https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Web+services+configuration seems to be not working.

The Wildfly is behind an Apache Httpd 2.2, usind `mod_proxy`.

```
ProxyPass         /     http://srv1:8080/
ProxyPassReverse  /     http://srv1:8080/
ProxyRequests     Off
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
```

In Wildfly, I configured

```
    ...
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.2">
        <modify-wsdl-address>true</modify-wsdl-address>
        <wsdl-host>jbossws.undefined.host</wsdl-host>
        <wsdl-port>80</wsdl-port>
        ...
```

in my `standalone.xml`. But when I request the Webservice wsdl via Apache Proxying using `http://srv1/MyWebservice?wsdl`, the port is not set to 80:

```
    ...
    <wsdl:service name="MyWebservice">
        <wsdl:port binding="tns:MyWebserviceSoapBinding" name="MyPort">
            <soap:address location="http://srv1:8080/MyWebservice"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
    ...
```

Any idea why this feature is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be working when I change the `standalone.xml` to explicitly set the host:

```
...
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.2">
    <modify-wsdl-address>true</modify-wsdl-address>
    <wsdl-host>srv1</wsdl-host>
    <wsdl-port>80</wsdl-port>
    ...
```

It might be a bug, but I'm not quite sure whether I'm using this correctly.